# AES Encryption Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, windows-phone-8.1, pcl-crypto

I need to do 128 bit AES encryption on an application in Windows Phone 8.1. I used the following code for Encrypting and Decrypting the data respectively:

```
    private string GetEncryptedContent(string content)
    {
        byte[] keyMaterial = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(EncryptionKey);
        byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content);
        var provider = WinRTCrypto.SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(SymmetricAlgorithm.AesCbcPkcs7);
        var key = provider.CreateSymmetricKey(keyMaterial);
        byte[] cipherText = WinRTCrypto.CryptographicEngine.Encrypt(key, data, null);
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(cipherText, 0, cipherText.Length);
    }

    private string GetDecryptedContent(string content)
    {
        byte[] keyMaterial = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(EncryptionKey);
        byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content);
        var provider = WinRTCrypto.SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(SymmetricAlgorithm.AesCbcPkcs7);
        var key = provider.CreateSymmetricKey(keyMaterial);
        byte[] cipherText = WinRTCrypto.CryptographicEngine.Decrypt(key, data, null);
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(cipherText, 0, cipherText.Length);
    }
```

But the encryption and decryption doesn't seem to be working properly. It is getting encrypted to some unicode characters and throwing a crash on decrypting:

> Length is not a multiple of block size and no padding is
>   selected.\r\nParameter name: ciphertext

What am I doing wrong here? Can someone please help?

**EDIT**

After a lot more time with Google, I found the following methods for encryption and decryption, but they doesn't seem to work either.

```
    public string GetEncryptedContent(string input, string pass)
    {
        SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider SAP = SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(SymmetricAlgorithmNames.AesEcbPkcs7);
        CryptographicKey AES;
        HashAlgorithmProvider HAP = HashAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(HashAlgorithmNames.Md5);
        CryptographicHash Hash_AES = HAP.CreateHash();

        string encrypted = "";
        try
        {
            byte[] hash = new byte[32];
            Hash_AES.Append(CryptographicBuffer.CreateFromByteArray(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pass)));
            byte[] temp;
            CryptographicBuffer.CopyToByteArray(Hash_AES.GetValueAndReset(), out temp);

            Array.Copy(temp, 0, hash, 0, 16);
            Array.Copy(temp, 0, hash, 15, 16);

            AES = SAP.CreateSymmetricKey(CryptographicBuffer.CreateFromByteArray(hash));

            IBuffer Buffer = CryptographicBuffer.CreateFromByteArray(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input));
            encrypted = CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToBase64String(CryptographicEngine.Encrypt(AES, Buffer, null));

            return encrypted;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }


    public string GetDecryptedContent(string input, string pass)
    {
        SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider SAP = SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(SymmetricAlgorithmNames.AesEcbPkcs7);
        CryptographicKey AES;
        HashAlgorithmProvider HAP = HashAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(HashAlgorithmNames.Md5);
        CryptographicHash Hash_AES = HAP.CreateHash();

        string decrypted = "";
        try
        {
            byte[] hash = new byte[32];
            Hash_AES.Append(CryptographicBuffer.CreateFromByteArray(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pass)));
            byte[] temp;
            CryptographicBuffer.CopyToByteArray(Hash_AES.GetValueAndReset(), out temp);

            Array.Copy(temp, 0, hash, 0, 16);
            Array.Copy(temp, 0, hash, 15, 16);

            AES = SAP.CreateSymmetricKey(CryptographicBuffer.CreateFromByteArray(hash));

            IBuffer Buffer = CryptographicBuffer.DecodeFromBase64String(input);
            byte[] Decrypted;
            CryptographicBuffer.CopyToByteArray(CryptographicEngine.Decrypt(AES, Buffer, null), out Decrypted);
            decrypted = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Decrypted, 0, Decrypted.Length);

            return decrypted;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

**EDIT 2**

Finally managed to get the encryption working properly, but the decryption is still not working presumably because the encoding I am passing is not the right one:

```
    private string GetEncryptedContent(string content)
    {
        byte[] keyMaterial = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(EncryptionKey);
        byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content);
        byte[] iv = new byte[128 / 8]; // Adding this solved the encryption issue.
        var provider = WinRTCrypto.SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(SymmetricAlgorithm.AesCbcPkcs7);
        var key = provider.CreateSymmetricKey(keyMaterial);
        byte[] cipherText = WinRTCrypto.CryptographicEngine.Encrypt(key, data, iv);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(cipherText);
    }

    private string GetDecryptedContent(string content)
    {
        byte[] keyMaterial = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(EncryptionKey);
        byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(content); // Believe this is where the issue is, but not able to figure it out.
        byte[] iv = new byte[128 / 8]; // Added this to make the decryption work the same way.
        var provider = WinRTCrypto.SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(SymmetricAlgorithm.AesCbcPkcs7);
        var key = provider.CreateSymmetricKey(keyMaterial);
        byte[] cipherText = WinRTCrypto.CryptographicEngine.Decrypt(key, data, iv);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(cipherText);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved the problem. The problem was with the text encoding. Using the correct encoding solved the issue. The working code below:

```
    public static string EncryptAES(string content, string password)
    {
        byte[] keyMaterial = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);
        byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content);
        byte[] iv = new byte[keyMaterial.Length];
        var provider = WinRTCrypto.SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(SymmetricAlgorithm.AesCbcPkcs7);
        var key = provider.CreateSymmetricKey(keyMaterial);
        byte[] cipherText = WinRTCrypto.CryptographicEngine.Encrypt(key, data, iv);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(cipherText);
    }

    public static string DecryptAES(string content, string password)
    {
        byte[] keyMaterial = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);
        byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(content);
        byte[] iv = new byte[keyMaterial.Length];
        var provider = WinRTCrypto.SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(SymmetricAlgorithm.AesCbcPkcs7);
        var key = provider.CreateSymmetricKey(keyMaterial);
        byte[] cipherText = WinRTCrypto.CryptographicEngine.Decrypt(key, data, iv);
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(cipherText, 0, cipherText.Length);
    }
```

`WinRTCrypto` is available as part of [**PCLCrypto**](https://www.nuget.org/packages/pclcrypto).